# If you agree, you 'nod'; if you don't agree, you _________?

Tags: word-request, word-usage

It is all about gestures and not uttering a word.

If you agree, you [*nod*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/nod_1?q=nod) i.e. move your head up and down. But what if you don't agree? Do we have a word *to describe the gesture?*

In short, what's opposite to 'nodding'?

Actually, the [Indian Head Shake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_bobble) is 'YES'; so, getting confused!

Comment: Watch out if you ever visit Bulgaria, they have it in reverse.

Comment: Yes @SF. on one level this question is really about culture. In the Arab world you pivot your head up and back one time slightly & quickly to signify no.

Comment: If you don't agree you can also just not nod.

Comment: @MaulikV I always wonder if the information on this Wikipedia page (about head shaking in India) is correct: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_shake#Shaking_head_to_indicate_rejection. I think that page could use an edit. ;-)

Comment: @DamkerngT. you cannot challenge me on this! I'm an Indian and in addition, a Gujarati... lol, typically what that page says. I, myself, though involuntarily, do that gesture. haha...

Comment: @MaulikV There is some misunderstanding here, I believe. Please read my comment again. There was no challenging. According to the page I linked to (which is a different page from the one I like to), *"Shaking to indicate "no" is widespread, [...] Areas in which head shaking generally takes this meaning include **Indian subcontinent**, Middle East, Africa, Southeast Asia, Europe, South America, North America and Australia."* Doesn't that contradict the reality in India, which you mentioned in the question? And since everyone can edit anything on Wikipedia, you might want to consider editing it.

Comment: @DamkerngT. You took it too seriously. It was a light comment.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You *Shake your head.*

Not to confuse with banging your hair around to the rhythm of music, or shaking water off your hair, you can add *shake your head "no"*.

Comment: Makes me wonder, is there a *shake your head "yes"*? I remember having read this somewhere, but that was Fantasy literature, so the author might have been taken liberties. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar: Read up the comments under the question.

Comment: '_smh_' is a commonly used slang informal acronym denoting '_shaking my head_' for when you "find something so stupid, no words can do it justice" ([Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=smh)).

Comment: @DevSolar *Shake your head "yes"* does exist. It's usually used in the past tense: *He shook his head yes.*

Comment: To be honest, "He shook" reads to me as "He shivered" despite all of the context.

Comment: Any literary history on this phrase?  I seem to recall many older works that I read in high school English where the phrase "he shook his head" actually meant agreement or yes.

Comment: @Darthfett: Unfortunately, I don't know, and this is ELL. For 'history of a phrase', [EL&U is this way](http://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I definitely do not think that *to shake one’s head* can **ever** be successfully or clearly abbreviated to *to shake*.

Comment: Well, I think you might be right - or at least the context would need to be much stronger than in the example.

Comment: Since there are regional differences, it’s maybe worth saying where this answer is valid.  I’m fairly confident that *shake your head* = *no* is standard (both as an action, and as the phrase for it) in most or all of the UK, Australia, New Zealand, Canada, and in parts of the States.  However, in some parts of the States, *shake your head yes* is also commonly used to describe nodding (as @MillieSmith says), so there you would have to clarify the negative version as *shake you head no*.  (To be clear: the *action* is the same all across the US, as far as I know, but the phrase for it varies.)

Comment: @PLL: I agree that we should note the regional differences, though where I am, *he shook his head* means "no" if "yes" is not specifically stated.

Comment: @MillieSmith: thanks for correcting me on that!  May I ask roughly where you’re from?  I’ve read *shake your head yes* from people online a few times, but I’ve never heard it in person (and in my own idiolect, it would be quite unnatural), so I would be interested to know what region(s) to attribute it to.

Comment: @PLL I grew up in Texas.

Comment: @PLL: Wouldn't "shaking your head yes" differ from plain nodding by meaning "nodding vigorously and enthusiastically"? (nod-nod-nod-nod-nod!)

Answer (score 7):

That depends on what you mean by *don't agree*.

If you mean *disagree; give a negative response; say no*, then you *shake your head*. This is the opposite of *nodding* (meaning it gives the opposite response; *negative* and *affirmative*, respectively) and different from the Indian head shake. In English, *shaking your head* means turning it side to side (to the right and left) a few times. It's a rotation around the vertical axis only; the head does not tilt or change its angle relative to the ground (assuming you're standing or sitting straight up). Here's a picture:

[image]

<sup>[source](http://newconnexion.net/articles/index.cfm/2009/07/Brain_Wave_Vibration_The_Secret_of_the_Brain_Stem.html)</sup>

From left to right, these are:

- Shaking your head
- Indian head shake / head bobble
- Nodding your head

But, if you mean *express that you don't assent or agree but also don't necessarily disagree; are hesitant, unsure, or of no particular opinion*, then you *shrug*. This necessarily involves raising the shoulders, but lifting the arms and/or a certain kind of facial expression are usually also involved. For example, if you're at the cinema with the man pictured below and had just said *what do you want to see? XYZ looks really good!*, you'd know that he *doesn't agree* with you, but doesn't particularly object to seeing XYZ either.

[image: enter link description here]

<sup>[source](https://www.cavstheblog.com/?attachment_id=11582)</sup>

One important thing to remember is that nonverbal communication is not necessarily the same across cultures, even when the language of choice is. In some places *shaking your head* means *yes*, so the natives there might misunderstand you even if you're having a conversation in fluent English.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "shake".This is not the opposite but you can use it like this.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Would you mind expanding your answer a little bit? I might be wrong but this seems just too unexplained and short to be a good ELL-worthy answer.

Comment: If someone told me to "shake", I would think hand-shake (or perhaps start a synchronized dance routine). Stating in full ("shake your head") would be necessary.

Answer (score -2):

This is a common phenomenon in most languages. It is an 'elliptical' phrase, which is derived from 'ellipsis', not 'squashed circle shape'. It means that part of the phraseology is left unspoken (elided), but the semantic content is 'understood' by the hearer/reader because they are familiar with the usage within that context.

The actual comparison in this instance of the phenomenon should be, "if you agree you 'nod [your head]'; if you disagree, you 'shake your head'. This correctly puts the emphasis on the use of 'nod' and removes it from 'shake'. And that eliminates most of the discussion of cultural and colloquial meanings and focuses attention on language structure, not usage.

If you become sensitive to this phenomenon, you will begin to notice its very ubiquitous influence. Almost every conversation you have will include, and most understandings will often hinge on, differing interpretations of statements in which elliptical phrases are central to the semantics.

It is also the foundation of most advertising slogans and almost all jokes. Which means it also has both visual and conceptual parallels. The basic proposition is that the *context* of our communication (meaning the conceptual grasp we have of our physical and intellectual environment) is subject to change based on the definitions that participants in a communication impose on the other participants. And it is proof that often the power and influence of a statement is based not on what is said, but what is not said. So a powerful or inspiring statement could build up a motivating context which the hearers might tend to identify with and then some aspect of the context can be left 'open' (the future, the contingencies, the key contribution, the missing link) and each listener then completes their internal context by filling in their personal impression of that unspoken item.

[Salvador Dali's 'surrealism'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salvador_Dal%C3%AD) is the most 'graphic' graphic example of the principle: introducing contrasting items will change our perception by altering the context of our internal, mental environment. The image is simply lines, spaces, and paint, but the semantics that Dali introduces forces the viewer to examine the process of how they internally assemble a semantic context of their moment-by-moment experience.

In the same way, a joke sets up a context that seems to mean one thing, but the punchline reveals that the context can and should be interpreted as something else entirely.

So the elliptical phrase is a key part of influencing people since it one of those flexible and malleable (can bend, can BE bent) components in the language capability that underlies all languages and constitutes the underlying logic that humans were given at their creation.

Comment: As down voted and disregarded this answer is - it truly holds merit and remarkable on its own. It deserves much better and a wider read.